# Embedded @Binding does not changing a value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Following [this cheat sheet](https://jaredsinclair.com/2020/05/07/swiftui-cheat-sheet.html) I'm trying to figure out data flow in SwiftUI. So:

> Use @Binding when your view needs to mutate a property owned by an ancestor view, or owned by an observable object that an ancestor has a reference to.

And that is exactly what I need so my embedded model is:

```swift
class SimpleModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var values: [String] = []

    init(values: [String] = []) {
        self.values = values
    }
}
```

and my View has two fields:

```swift
struct SimpleModelView: View {
    @Binding var model: SimpleModel
    @Binding var strings: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(self.strings[0])
                TextField("name", text: self.$strings[0])
            }
            HStack {
                Text(self.model.values[0])
                EmbeddedView(strings: self.$model.values)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EmbeddedView: View {
    @Binding var strings: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("name", text: self.$strings[0])
        }
    }
}
```

So I expect the view to change `Text` when change in input field will occur. And it's working for `[String]` but does not work for embedded @Binding object:

[image]

Why it's behaving differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make property published

```
class SimpleModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var values: [String] = []
```

and `model` observed

```
struct SimpleModelView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: SimpleModel
```

Note: this in that direction - if you introduced `ObservableObject` then corresponding view should have `ObservedObject` wrapper to observe changes of that observable object's published properties.

Comment: Did that - same issue unfortunately

Comment: Great! Thanks now it's working and understand principle here, but still not sure why @Binding with @Published as you suggested in a first time it's not working  From my understanding the docs and description it should change `Text` same way since it's "bind"

Answer (score 1):

In SimpleModelView, try changing:

```
@Binding var model: SimpleModel
```

to:

```
@ObservedObject var model: SimpleModel
```

`@ObservedObjects` provide binding values as well, and are required if you want state changes from classes conforming to `ObservableObject`